# Calculating logarithms in Java with different bases

Tags: logarithm

I would like to calculate logX(Y) in Java. However I don't understand why I get 3.0 when I calculate Math.log10(1000), and yet I get 2.9999999999999996 when  I calculate double x = Math.log(1000) / Math.log(10).

Here are my efforts thus far:

```
public class log_bases {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double k = logOfBase(10,1000);
        System.out.println(k);                  // this outputs 2.99999999
        System.out.println(Math.log10(1000));   // this outputs 3.0
        double x = Math.log(1000) / Math.log(10);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static double logOfBase(int base, int num) {
        return Math.log(num) / Math.log(base);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the floating-point representation and round-off issues. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/even-simple-floating-point-output-is-com/240165594

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I'll read the article straight away. :)